# Cross correlation between 2 filtered time series

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation, filter

I have 2 band pass filtered time series for 30-90 day band I would like to understand the lagged correlation between these 2 series in this band. The issue is that autocorrelations exist in both series and also the effect of filtering. I am unclear on how to separate out these and find the true lagged relation if any among the 2 series. Apparently there is a strong lagged correlation between the two series around 10 days lag. And there is strong ACF in both series at around 20 days. So it is difficult for me to interpret the cross correlation.

The plot is at below:

[image]

The data is at below link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3heUQNme7G5T2JjeTlDNzdkX00/view?usp=sharing

R code:

```
dc = read.csv('test_dat.csv', header=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
acf(dc$sst, 365)
acf(dc$t2m, 365)
ccf(dc$sst, dc$t2m, 365)
```

Comment: Welcome to CV! If you like, you can also add your plot using the "Image button" in the "Editor window".

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it gave error saying format is not supported. I tried both pdf and png version which did not work.

Comment: What is the subject-matter context here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to understand lagged relation between 2 filtered time series. This type of analysis is needed to understand the intra-seasonal scale association between sea-surface temperature and air temperature

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-January/435316.html